# Problems inside the mesh using boolean modifier (2.8)

Tags: modifiers

I did a boolean (union) between 2 equal pieces but I got a weird problem inside of my item. I want a solid piece in order to add another boolean on it.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it is not a solid piece? You can try this by selecting connected vertices with the "L"-key. To me it just looks like a lot of unnecessary edges in the corner which you might consider cleaning up a bit... Does the next boolean fail?

Comment: Boolean usage has some constraints. But you should describe a bit more you final objective if you want to get some help. What is the third piece you want to use?

Comment: I did a Union, but Robert is right, it's lot of unnecessary edges. But unfortunately I don't have idea how to clean it =(

Comment: If you have not precalculated the amount of vertices for the round/cylinder part (depending on the relative rotations), that will be a mess. Boolean is easy to use, but cleaning the unwanted consequences is often difficult and requires a lot of manual work, if not pre-thinking. Again you should indicate where you want to go with the additional part you want to union with this, and the angles between this two parts.